# Java - JAXB - Unmarshalling : How to achieve the correct set up?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm currently trying to change lots of XML into Java objects but I keep getting stuck. I have tried copying lots of different examples online but I can never seem to get the right way and I find it very hard to debug.

My XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
  <TeamLeagueStanding xmlns="http://xmlsoccer.com/LeagueStanding">
    <Team>Leicester</Team>
    <Team_Id>31</Team_Id>
    <Played>26</Played>
    <PlayedAtHome>12</PlayedAtHome>
    <PlayedAway>14</PlayedAway>
    <Won>15</Won>
    <Draw>8</Draw>
    <Lost>3</Lost>
    <NumberOfShots>464</NumberOfShots>
    <YellowCards>40</YellowCards>
    <RedCards>1</RedCards>
    <Goals_For>48</Goals_For>
    <Goals_Against>29</Goals_Against>
    <Goal_Difference>19</Goal_Difference>
    <Points>53</Points>
  </TeamLeagueStanding>
  <TeamLeagueStanding xmlns="http://xmlsoccer.com/LeagueStanding">
    <Team>Tottenham</Team>
    <Team_Id>21</Team_Id>
...
```

So I just have a list of `TeamLeagueStanding` s that I want to keep as Team objects. My java code for the Team class is currently like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TeamLeagueStanding")
public class Team {

    @XmlElement(name = "Team")
    String teamName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Team_Id")
    int teamID;

    public Team (String team, int id) {
        super();
        this.teamName = team;
        this.teamID = id;
    }

}
```

My Teams class which is just to hold the list of Teams is like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "XMLSOCCER.COM")
public class Teams {

    @XmlElement
    List<Team> teamList;

    public Teams () {

    }

}
```

and my main function is like this

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File xml = new File("data/GetLeagueStandingsPrem1516.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Teams.class);
        Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        Teams t = (Teams) um.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(t.teamList.size());

    }

}
```

I've tried this so many ways and I always get either a null pointer exception or various `IllegalAnnotationExceptions`. If anyone has any idea where I'm going wrong I would greatly appreciate any pointers!

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Consider to specify an XSD and generate the JAXB classes using xjc. (Note: a root element is only valid at the root)

Comment: So I think the problem is with my XML rather than my Java - I deleted the xmlns attributes and the code below worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "TeamLeagueStanding")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Team {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root element seems to be XMLSOCCER.COM

1. create xsd 
2. using xjc command create java bean classes or you can use IDE to create objects.
3.keep created xml bean objects under src
4. then you pass the xml to be unmarshelled
5. you will get converted objects hierarchically you can access.

Comment: Actually I would recommend to call xjc via maven-jaxb2-plugin, which also generates the JAXB classes under target by default. You should not check them into your VCS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add default constructor to `Team` class
2. Add

   ```
   @XmlElement(name = "TeamLeagueStanding")
   List<Team> teamList;
   ```

   to `Teams` class;

---

**Team.class**:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "TeamLeagueStanding")
public class Team {

    @XmlElement(name = "Team")
    String teamName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Team_Id")
    int teamID;

    public Team (){

    }

    public Team (String team, int id) {
        super();
        this.teamName = team;
        this.teamID = id;
    }
}
```

**Teams.class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "XMLSOCCER.COM")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Teams {

    @XmlElement(name = "TeamLeagueStanding")
    List<Team> teamList;

    public Teams () {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this and I'm getting a NullPointerEx on the teamList